# MongoDB - How to show all tasks of user logged in

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model, aggregation-framework

So I have 3 models: User, Projects and Tasks...

and I want to show in my dashboard all the tasks of user projects of the user that is logged in, but what's happening is that when I logged in as, for example, "user1" it shows all tasks from collection and as "user2" shows as well all tasks from collection... and I want to show only the tasks from the user logged in..

My User don't contain the tasks, only the projects, and I thought I could use aggregate lookup to do it but I don't know how to use it and I don't know if it's the best way to do it

**User Model:**

```
    let mongoose = require("mongoose");
    let passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

    let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    username: String,
    password: String,
    companyname: String,
    companyimageURL: String,
    projects: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    }]
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**Project Model:**

```
 let mongoose = require("mongoose");

 let projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    projectname: String,
    typeofproject: String,
    imageURL: String,
    dateMonthFrom: String,
    dateYearFrom: String,
    dateMonthTo: String,
    dateYearTo: String,
    tasks: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Tasks'
    }],
    user: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

**Tasks Model:**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    tasktitle: String,
    taskcomment: String,
    project: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project'
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', taskSchema);
```

**my server side**:

```
exports.render_all_tasks = (req, res) => {


User.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: 'projects',
            localField: 'projects',
            foreignField: 'tasks',
            as: 'user'
                }
        }
]).exec((err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    Task.find({}).populate('project').exec((err, tasks) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

            res.send(tasks);

          });   
    });
};
```

**users collection:**

```
       {
           _id: ObjectId("..."),
           projects: [ 0: ObjectId("..."), 1: ObjectId("...")],
           username: "user1",
           companyname: "company1",
           companyimageURL: "..."

        }
```

**projects collection:**

```
       {
           _id: ObjectId("..."),
           tasks: [ 0: ObjectId("..."), 1: ObjectId("...")],
           user:  [ 0: ObjectId("...")],
           projectname: "project1",
           typeofproject: "type1",
           imageURL: "..."

        }
```

**tasks collection:**

```
       {
           _id: ObjectId("..."),
           project: [ 0: ObjectId("..."),
           tasktitle: "Task 1"

        }
```

Comment: You can save user id inside the `Tasks` model. Btw what is your mongodb version?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I was trying to avoid doing that because I wanted to keep tasks only inside projects and projects inside users, but if I don't find a solution, I have to do that of course. My version is  v4.0.2

Comment: Putting single parent field  in child is always a better option to make other CRUD operation easier. Anyways you can go with veeram's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly query the projects collection to get the tasks for logged in user.

Something like

```
Project.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"user":logged in user}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"tasks",
    "localField":"tasks",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"tasks"
  }}
])
```

OR

You can use below aggregation in 3.6 to query from user collection. This will fetch all the tasks across all the projects for each user.

```
User.aggregate([{
  "$lookup":{
    "from":"projects",
    "let":{"projects":"$projects","user":"$_id"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{
        "$expr":{
          "$and":[
            {"$in":["$_id","$$projects"]},
            {"$in":["$$user","$user"]}
          ]
        }}
      },
      {"$lookup":{
        "from":"tasks",
        "localField":"tasks",
        "foreignField":"_id",
        "as":"tasks"
      }}
    ],
    "as":"project-tasks"
  }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This aggregate doesn't work, maybe it's because my mongodb version is v4.0.2 ?

Comment: Yw. Not really. Do you get any error ? I've added an alternative to query the projects collection directly.

Comment: Didn't get any error, maybe I have to add tasks to user and user to each task, I was trying to avoid that, but maybe it's the simple way to do it

Comment: Did you try the alternative I have added ? That may be simpler for your use case.

Comment: I did, but doesn't do anything and I don't get any error as well, it's really weird, because at least could give me an error or something

Comment: Alright I can help you more if you can show me sample documents from each collection.

Comment: I'm new at this (mongodb), I updated my question, is that what you say as documents from each collection?

Comment: yes that is what I needed. Can you do me a favor and run the query in mongo shell ? `db.projects.aggregate({"$match":{"user":logged in user}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"tasks",
    "localField":"tasks",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"tasks"
  }})`. Also please verify the collection names are correct.Just would like to isolate the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181364/discussion-between-veeram-and-ana-fig).